# How to modify the Account field of GL Impact on the invoice page through suitescript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

According to different conditions, I need to modify the account field in GL Impact. I am still a novice. Who can tell me how to modify the GL Impact on the invoice page through suitescript? Greatful

Answer (score 1):

Customization -> Plugins -> Plugin Implementations.

You will need to create a GL Plugin that will run on every submit event. You cannot change the existing GL lines as far as I know but you CAN "re-allocate them" by creating new lines that balance the book.

Here are a few URL extensions to articles on the help regarding how to create a script of this type:

```
/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4072818715.html
/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4072803104.html
/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_3989534344.html
```